# Retrieve Last Object in List of JSON Objects

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a list of JSON objects returned from an AJAX request:

```
Object {id: 1, name: "Ben Roethlisberger"}
Object {id: 2, name: "Antonio Brown"}
Object {id: 3, name: "Le'Veon Bell"}
```

I can access `name` from a single object with the following

```
e.data.name
```

Is there any way I can retrieve the very last object from the list, and grab that object's name?

Comment: If the actual return from the AJAX request is as you show, it is not JSON and will not parse as such. The request should not return such a "list" of objects; it should return an **array** of objects. At that point, you can access the last one by simply saying `json[json.length - 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

If your response is:

```
var response = [
  {id: 1, name: "Ben Roethlisberger"},
  {id: 2, name: "Antonio Brown"},
  {id: 3, name: "Le'Veon Bell"}
]
```

You can do:

```
var lastObjectName = response[response.length - 1].name;

for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
   var name = response[i].name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there your json data:

```
var data = [ {id: 1, name: "Ben Roethlisberger"}
, {id: 2, name: "Antonio Brown"},
{id: 3, name: "Le'Veon Bell"}];
```

You can access name from a single object with the following, with index start by 0:

```
data[index].name
```

Each object has length, list start index by zero, you can access last object in list by:

```
data[data.length-1].name
```

Here is example:
http://jsfiddle.net/oht1mke9/

Answer (score 0):

Just use array.pop() and then access the object properties as needed.

So...

```
var list = [{ a: '1'}, {b: '2'}];
var lastObject = list.pop();

if(lastObject) {
 //use object..
}
```